# Creating a modifiable table with javascript and then deleting it

Tags: javascript, html

`I'm trying to make a self-study exam of 152 statistics problems on a single webpage. I am measuring the clicks and setting if else if conditionals to update the webpage with the different questions. Question 19 has a table that is created locally using JavaScript because I want to be able to randomize its contents. It's still printing in question 20 as its value is coming back with null once it gets to this conditional. So question 20 is still displaying question 19's table with no actual way of deleting it. How can I modify my code to make the table accessible in conditionals where clicks do not equal 19?

```
Essentially this is the code that made the table
```

```
 else if (current-clicks == 19){
    const body = document.body
    tbl = document.creatElement('table');
    tbl.style.width = '100px';`
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';`
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  // vertical `
    const tr = tbl.insertRow(); //creates rows`
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) { // horizontal `
    const td = tr.insertCell(); // creates cells`

    // if/ else if conditionals that randomize the cell's contents using 
    // const textNode = document.createTextNode("x"); td.appendChild(textNode);
    td.style.border = '1px solid black';
    }
 }
  body.appendChild(tbl);


    }  

else if (current-clicks == 20){
    var removeTable = document.getElementById('table');
    var parent1 = removeTable.parentNode;
    parent1.removeChild(removeTable);`
    }
```

I was expecting the current-clicks == 20 code to delete the table. However the table is local so it cannot be deleted this way. `

Comment: This fixed it thank you!  It deletes the table because question 20 is just a word problem that doesn't need the table element. Question 19 you need data from the table to be able to solve the statistics problem. It's for actuarial exam p studying.